# Как остановить воспроизведение MediaPlayer при достижении определенной секунды?

Tags: android

У меня такая задача нужно один mp3 файл воспроизводить при нажатии разных кнопок, только у каждой кнопки разные начала воспроизведения, например кнопка 1 должно восприозводиться с 53 секунды mp3 файл, это делается с помощью mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - 53000 , а как можно остановить при достижении мп3 56 секунды например?

Comment: у меня только предположение - запустить sleep на 3 секунды - и остановить воспроизведение.

Comment: спасибо, даже не подумал об этом, вполне возможно решит проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно просто поставить `CountDownTimer` :

```
public void MyFunction(int milisec){

 new CountDownTimer(milisec, 1000){
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){

                }
                public  void onFinish(){
                   stopMediaPlayer();
                }
            }.start();

}
```